# Convert image url to file JavaScript

Tags: javascript, converters

What the reason that I can't convert png url? With jpg works well

```
const getFileFromUrl = async (url, defaultType = 'image/jpeg') => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.blob();

    return new File([data], url, {
      type: response.headers.get('content-type') || defaultType,
    });
  };

const pngUrl = 'https://pngimg.com/uploads/smoke/smoke_PNG55226.png';

const jpgUrl = 'picsum.photos/id/930/536/354.jpg';

getFileFromUrl(pngUrl).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: 'image/jpeg' is just the default value of defaultType. It will be used only if `response.headers.get('content-type')` doesn't exist. @itwaze: Can you log what is printed by `response.headers.get('content-type')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not about the filetypes but the CORS configurations of the pngimg.com server. Their server basically doesn't allow you to access their resources from another domain. Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin):

> The response to the CORS request is missing the required Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, which is used to determine whether or not the resource can be accessed by content operating within the current origin.

> If the server is under your control, add the origin of the requesting site to the set of domains permitted access by adding it to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header's value.

This png will work fine with your code: https://dummyimage.com/420x320/ff7f7f/333333.png&text=Sample

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example it seems like pngimg.com doesn't allow CORS.

While picsum.photos does. For example works fine.

```
webp = 'https://i.picsum.photos/id/294/200/300.webp?hmac=TfUv_Mk33Jmph_emWudbTWVO4e60vnZnJHp_f4emHEo'

getFileFromUrl(webp).then((d) => {
  console.log(d);
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I couldn't find a source which hosts png and allows CORS. But above example uses webp to demonstrate that its not really PNG issue as such.

### Update

As @KiwiKilian posted png image URL, it seems to be working just fine. For example

```
let png = 'https://dummyimage.com/420x320/ff7f7f/333333.png&text=Sample'

getFileFromUrl(png).then((d) => {
  console.log(d);
}).catch(err => console.log(err))
```